# Do Prepositions Alter Meaning of a Subject?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning, grammaticality, prepositional-phrases, infinitive-phrases

Do prepositions alter the meaning of a subject in a way that changes what the verb's compliment is referring to? (Specifically infinitive phrase compliments)

Examples:

1. I work `at my position in time` to have pie. [Does `at my position in time` make "to have pie" refer to me specifically at my position in time has pie or I at any time have pie]
2. Larry `under the table` fears to stand up. [Does `under the table` change the subject for "to stand up" to mean: if Larry was not under the table he might not fear to stand up]

If prepositions do alter the meaning of a subject, what could I do to make those infinitive phrases refer to the subject without the preposition?

(I know I'm trying too much to have no confusion in the meaning, however the situation requires this level of scrutiny.)

---

**Edit:
It has been proven that prepositions after the subject alter the meaning of the subject.  However it has not been answered whether prepositions after the verb alter the meaning of the subject.**

Comment: I would say yes, since the subject is the entire phrase. "*A man with a vial of nitroglycerin* fears to be jostled."  or "*An animal in a corner* is especially dangerous."

Comment: There is no way to make the infinitival complements not pertain to the subject of the verb apart from changing the subject.

Comment: The first sentence is hard for me to understand.  I'm not sure what you mean, but "I work at my position in time" doesn't really make sense to me.  It sounds like my position is somewhere in time, which is a very strange way to speak unless you are a time traveller.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo But, wouldn't `at my position in time` be an adverb for work.  Or would that still alter the subject I in the sentence?

Comment: @Stangdon, try regarding "at my position" as one phrase and "in time to have pie" as another, each of them modifying the verb "work".  Perhaps OP gets to his job early enough to indulge in a lemon meringue breakfast.

Comment: @user58712: I did not understand  your first example and was responding to the "Larry" example.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan - Hmm, good interpretation.  Still sounds a little weird to me, since "I work" is normally kind of an ongoing process, not an instantaneous event like "I arrive at work", but probably the only reasonable way to interpret it.  Certainly if someone said, "I arrive at the house in time to have pie" I wouldn't think the house was located somewhere in time...

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan `at my position in time` means where I am in time, thinking of time in terms of a dimension (like an x or y axis).

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo at my position in time means where I am in time, thinking of time in terms of a dimension (like an x or y axis).

Comment: @user58712 - A more idiomatic way to say that would be "at this time" or even "right now".

Comment: @stangdon That doesn't work [Link](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/410432/how-to-make-a-statement-always-in-present-tense)

Comment: @user58712 - I'm not sure what you're trying to say, especially since the question you link to was "closed as unclear".

Comment: @stangdon "at this time" refers to this point in time (its static), but my position in time is whatever point in time I happen to be at (its dynamic).

Comment: @user58712 - I don't think English really has a tense like that.  You could just say "I work to have pie", which is nonspecific about time; it just means "Whenever I work, I do it for the purpose of having pie."

Comment: @stangdon That problem is already solved, "at my position in time" is the answer.  I'm just telling you why "at this time" or "right now" doesn't work.

Comment: @user58712 - OK, but in the opinion of this native English speaker, "at my position in time" sounds weird and non-fluent.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure what you're asking. Of course a prepositional phrase alters the meaning of the sentence. If it didn't, why would the writer include it?

"Larry under the table fears to stand up." "Under the table" here is a restrictive clause: It tells us which Larry you are talking about. You wouldn't say this unless there was some other Larry, who presumably is not under the table, that this Larry might be confused with. If you want to inform us that Larry is under the table, you should say, "Larry, who is under the table, fears to stand up." In either case, the GRAMMAR does not tell us whether Larry would be afraid to stand up if he was not under the table. It might be clear from the context, or it might not. The person making the statement might or might not know if Larry would be afraid to stand up under other circumstances.

Consider these similar sentences: "Larry who failed the entrance exam will not go to college." In this case it seems likely that if he had passed the entrance exam, he would be going to college. But, "Larry wearing a red shirt is a good driver." Presumably wearing a red shirt does not make him a good driver. The speaker is likely telling us that he is wearing a red shirt to distinguish him from some other Larry who is wearing a different color shirt.

Answer (score 0):

When the subject of a verb consists of a noun and a prepositional phrase, the phrase is an integral attribute of the noun.

> A man in disguise may be difficult to spot.
>
> A child with a pointy stick is an accident waiting to happen.
>
> An ex-con with a record of violent crime may find it difficult to get
>   a job.
>
> People in glass houses should not throw stones.
>
> The girl in the blue shirt is my cousin.

If the verb has an infinitival complement, the subject-with-prepositional-phrase is subject of the entire verb phrase:

> {A man with a vial of nitroglycerin} {fears {to be jostled} }.
>
> {The horse with the spot on its forehead} {likes {to have its ears scratched}}

Comment: I agree with all that you said.  However would a prepositional phrase used as an adverb be an integral aspect of the verb instead of the noun.  So instead:  {A man}{fears{with a vial of nitroglycerin}{to be jostled}}.

Comment: @user58712: That sentence is not idiomatic.  You would need to recast the prepositional phrase as a circumstantial *when*-clause:  "A man fears, *when he is holding a vial of nitroglycerin*, to be jostled".  The circumstantial does indeed color the verb phrase: "*When he is holding a vial of nitroglycerin*, a man fears to be jostled."

Comment: So would "A man fears, at the time of holding a vial of nitroglycerin, to be jostled" be an integral aspect of the verb instead of the noun.

Comment: @user58712: "at the time of holding" is not idiomatic. It's not outright ungrammatical, but "at the time of" is at best "legalese" or some other -ese for "when".  **at the time of holding** doesn't make aspectual sense. **at** is point-in-time whereas **holding** is continuous.

Comment: Ignoring that specific example, would any preposition after the verb be an integral aspect (or defining aspect) of the noun?

Comment: @user58712: First, you're using the term "aspect" differently than I used it in the comment directly above, where I' was referring to temporal characteristics.  Second, which verb are you referring to? You've been giving examples with two verbs (e.g. fears to stand up). Third, please provide an example where a preposition occurs after the verb. Do you mean a prepositional phrase?

Comment: I meant to say attribute instead of aspect.  No specific verb (unless a different verb might change an answer, if so, then I'm referring to strive). Yes, I mean a prepositional phrase.  And your "fears to stand up" example should work (although I'm not using "fears to stand up" so I don't care about specifics to the example, rather specifics to the answer to any situation where this occurs).  So lets say the example is, "Peter fears to stand up."

Comment: @user58712: It is not clear to me whether you are referring to a single preposition like **up** (in *stand up*) or to a prepositional phrase, as in the examples in your question (*under the table*, *at my job*, etc).

Comment: @user58712:  Are you thinking of a sentence like this: *He strives **in the morning** to run five miles.*  That's not quite idiomatic, in my view. Do you want the PP to appear directly after **strives**?

Comment: @user58712: if you're asking about the difference between **stand** and **stand up**, yes, **up** does convey meaning, much like the perfect.  There's a difference between "The children are standing" and "The children are standing up". The version with **up** refers to the action-in-progress-attaining-completion.  There a big difference between **run** and **run away**.

Comment: Answers to your questions in order: a prepositional phrase, and no.  I'm asking the following: Does a prepositional phrase after a verb, or prepositional phrase after a prepositional phrase (which is after a verb) alter the subject?

Comment: @user58712: I have no clear idea what you mean by "alter" a subject, but I will say that if the subject is doing something, and if the prepositional phrase qualifies the action, then the subject's action is being "altered" (if we use that word loosely). *The dancer stepped into the circle.*   Is being outside the circle and then inside the circle a "subject alteration"?  You tell me. Am I talking to someone who is trying to learn English or a follower of Heraclitus?

Comment: I would say not, but that's why I'm asking this question (to make sure I'm right). I read that a prepositional is only a modifier of a nouns, but I guess they were wrong.  If I understand your answer correctly.